# hello.js Get facebook friends doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript, hello.js

So im just using the sites example provided in

https://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/friends.html#helloapi-mefriends-

and i cant seem to be able to get the friend list, with facebook. It seems to work ok with google but not facebook

if i go to the hello.api() section of the site and click on the play button next to me/friends i get

```
{
 data: [],
 summary: {
  total_count: 240
 }
}
```

which seems to be the friends count. is this broken ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook changed the way the me/friends endpoint works, it now shows only your friends who are also using the application.